# Ensure WordPress Theme Uninstalls Completely

Tags: plugins, themes

How can I make sure my WordPress is clean of any old files from previous themes so I can install a new theme with no issues from past themes/plugins.

The goal here is I am planning to install a premium theme for my existing WP site and use Divi Plugin

So far I've tried contacting Bluehost but they just did a 'scan' or something so I don't know if they understood what I meant. I'm relatively new to WP. Tinkering for about 2 years. I've tried google searching and irrelevant articles pop up. When searching this site I got 0 results. Hope I'm articulating my question well.

Comment: All a theme's files are enclosed in its theme directory. You don't need to "clean" anything out. Simply add your new theme, and switch to it in the admin.

Comment: Thank you for your speedy reply

Answer (score 0):

Just activate a new theme and remove the previous in the CMS. You won’t need to log into the database to clear anything out.

Comment: How do you remove the previous? Is it automatic?

Comment: Admin > Appearance > Themes - select anythemes you want to remove.